# Web Sharing not working? "Could Not Share Post"

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've got the FB JS SDK loaded and a Facebook Developer App made (which is live). I want to use their "Web Sharing" feature to make a simple button that opens a dialog to share the current page to your timeline.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

The code I'm using:

```
FB.ui({ 
  method: 'share',
  href: 'mywebsite.com',
}, function(response){});
```

And it gives me this error when clicked:

> Could Not Share Post: Sorry, the post that you're sharing couldn't be
>   loaded. It may have been recently deleted.

But it works when I substitute the URL for `google.ca`.

Is there something I'm doing wrong? I have the website URL and app domain set in the FB Developers app.

Good thing they took away that simple link you used to be able to just append your URL to in a GET parameter to share. ¯\(ツ)/¯

Comment: You should use proper, absolute URLs. And the page has to be publicly reachable (people sometimes forget that, when testing in a local dev environment.)

Comment: Sorry, the example is contrived but it is a full URL with protocol and all. The point is that it won't let me use that, but it will let me use other websites not on the domain like google.ca.

Comment: Can you post that URL manually directly on Facebook - or do you get any warnings/errors then that it was blocked? What does the FB debug tool say about the URL?

Comment: _“Good thing they took away that simple link you used to be able to just append your URL to in a GET parameter to share”_ - `https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={url-to-share}` still works. And the Share and Feed dialog can be called by simple sending the user to a specific URL, too, they just require a few extra parameters.

Comment: http://www.saskwastereduction.ca/blog/green-living/2017/03/17/just-say-no-to-styrofoam/ The link in question. @CBro You're definitely right, that does still work but not for this link.

Comment: Hm, the debug tool doesn't even give a response for that. File a bug report, it looks like a mess-up on their end. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: Thanks, I've opened up a bug report